# LWC - Custom Picklist Type Not Rendering in Datatable

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have created an lwc datatable and I am attempting to display an editable custom picklist dropdown in one of the columns.

I've followed the Salesforce documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_table_custom_types) but am running into issues with the cell not pulling in the combobox and picklist values.

I'm still a novice with LWCs so greatly appreciate any help.

[image]

**Datatable Component**

JS

```
    import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
    import getUncategorizedDocuments from '@salesforce/apex/onboardingReviewDocumentsController.getUncategorizedDocuments';
    import { updateRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
    import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
    import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';
    import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
    import { getPicklistValues } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
    import ONB_APP_DOC_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/onb_Onboarding_Application_Document__c';
    import TYPE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/onb_Onboarding_Application_Document__c.Document_Type__c';
    
    // columns
    const columns = [
        {
            label: 'Onboarding Application Document Name',
            fieldName: 'Name',
            type: 'text'
        }, {
            label: 'Document Type',
            fieldName: 'Document_Type__c',
            type: 'typePicklist',
            editable: true,
            wrapText: true,
                typeAttributes: {
                    options: { fieldName : 'picklistOptions' },
                    value: { fieldName : 'Document_Type__c'},
                    placeholder: 'Choose a Document Type',
                }
        }, 
    ];
    
    export default class OnboardingFileLabelRemediation extends LightningElement {
        columns = columns;
        onbAppDocs = [];
        onbAppDocType = [];
    
        @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: ONB_APP_DOC_OBJECT })
        onbAppDocObjectMetadata;
    
        @wire(getPicklistValues, { recordTypeId: '$onbAppDocObjectMetadata.data.defaultRecordTypeId', fieldApiName: TYPE_FIELD })
        onbAppDocTypePicklist ({ data, error }) {
            if (data) {
                this.onbAppDocType = data.values;
                this.fetchUncategorizedDocuments();
            }
        }
        
        fetchUncategorizedDocuments() {
            getUncategorizedDocuments()
                .then((result) => {
    
                    let options = [];
                    for(var key in this.onbAppDocType){
                            options.push( { label: this.onbAppDocType[key].label, value: this.onbAppDocType[key].value });
                    }
                    this.onbAppDocs = result.map((record) => {
                        return {
                            ...record,
                            'picklistOptions': options
                        }
                    })
                this.error = undefined;
                })
        }
    
        async handleSave(event) {
            // Convert datatable draft values into record objects
            const records = event.detail.onbAppDocs.slice().map((draftValue) => {
                const fields = Object.assign({}, draftValue);
                return { fields };
            });
    
            // Clear all datatable draft values
            this.onbAppDocs = [];
    
            try {
                // Update all records in parallel thanks to the UI API
                const recordUpdatePromises = records.map((record) =>
                    updateRecord(record)
                );
                await Promise.all(recordUpdatePromises);
    
                // Report success with a toast
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Success',
                        message: 'Application Documents updated',
                        variant: 'success'
                    })
                );
    
                // Display fresh data in the datatable
                await refreshApex(this.onbAppDocs);
            } catch (error) {
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Error updating or reloading Onboarding Applications',
                        message: error.body.message,
                        variant: 'error'
                    })
                );
            }
        }
    }
```

HTML

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Uncategorized Onboarding Application Documents" icon-name="standard:document">
           <c-custom-type-global 
                    key-field="Id"
                    data={onbAppDocs.data} 
                    columns={columns} 
                    onsave={handleSave}
                    draft-values={saveDraftValues} 
                    hide-checkbox-column
                    show-row-number-column = true>
           </c-custom-type-global>
       <template if:true={onbAppDocs.error}>
                <!-- handle Apex error -->
       </template>
   </lightning-card>
</template>
```

**Custom Type Component**

JS

```
import LightningDatatable from 'lightning/datatable';
import customPicklist from './customPicklist.html';

export default class CustomTypeGlobal extends LightningDatatable {
    static customTypes = {
        typePicklist: {
            template: customPicklist,
            standardCellLayout: true,
            typeAttributes: ['label', 'value', 'placeholder', 'options']
        }
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<template>
    <lightning-combobox
        name = "picklist"
        label ={typeAttributes.label}
        value ={typeAttributes.value}
        placeholder ={typeAttributes.placeholder}
        options ={typeAttributes.options}>
    </lightning-combobox>
</template>
```

Comment: Try adding data-inputable="true" for lightning combobox.   

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    <lightning-combobox 
         name="picklist" 
         data-inputable="true"
         label={typeAttributes.label}
         value={editedValue}
         placeholder={typeAttributes.placeholder} 
         options={typeAttributes.options} 
         variant='label-hidden'
         dropdown-alignment="auto">
</lightning-combobox>

_____________________________________________________________